# HttpWebRequest return value different from brower, maybe a cookie

Tags: c#, xml, http, httpwebrequest

Trying to access an XML online, using HttpWebRequest and the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/example.xml") as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

When I browse the URL, I can see the XML but variable data contains the following:

```
<html><body><script>document.cookie='lllllll=e0b70895lllllll_e0b70895; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;</script></body></html>
```

I've checked **webResponse.Cookies** but it's empty.

How can I get past this using the webrequest and get the xml into the data variable?

Answer (score 0):

All what you wrote is correct. The problem is in your case (but it's a good solution against the robots), the cookie added by Javascript and not in the HTTP response.

```
document.cookie='lllllll=e0b70895lllllll_e0b70895; path=/'
```

This line of JavaScript code sets the cookie. So it's needs to set in the code after this response. You can do that easily with the `CookieContainer.Add()` method.

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

This line of code just refresh the page, but if in the browser the cookie is already set, that's why you can get the response.

To get this cookie, you need to use regex, because I think the name of the cookie is dynamic too.

So you need to add something like this:

```
// Catch the cookie name and value with using regex, than remove the
// characters what we only need for the regex match.

string cookieName = Regex.Match(data, "'[a-z]*").Value.Remove(0, 1);
string cookieValue = Regex.Match(data, "=[a-zA-Z0-9]*").Value.Remove(0, 1);

webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookieName,cookieValue));
webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
string data = sr2.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your code but it doesn't work and data comes back empty this time. cookiename = "lllllll" and cookieValue = "". I think there's a problem there...